# The multi-part identifier "sxxx@yahoo.com" could not be bound

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
if (validateEmailId(email))
{
    pictureBox5.Visible = true;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("conection string");
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  sumant SET email=" + email + " WHERE code ='" + textBox2.Text + "' ", con);
    cmd2.Connection = con;
    cmd2.Connection.Open();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();//line 7
    con.Close();
}
```

validateEmailId is a function which validates the email entered(using regular expression)..
The email entered in the 'email' textbox is validated and is returned to the above function..

When the control passes to line 7 following error is encountered:

> The multi-part identifier "sxxx@yahoo.com" could not be bound.

It means `sxxx@yahoo.com` has passed the validation test, but a problem occurred in line 7.

On the SQL end, the column 'email' has `varchar(50)` as its data type...I don't think that's an issue....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ouch, I smell SQL injection and lack of disposal. Try this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("conection string")) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE sumant SET email=@Email WHERE code = @Code", con)) {
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", textBox2.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The using directives will close the SqlConnection and SqlCommand no matter if they fail or execute properly. The SqlParameters will prevent any form of SQL injection.

Another sidenote: your passing the conn argument to the SqlCommand constructor AND are setting the connection property of the SqlCommand after that, passing the SqlConnection to the SqlCommand already sets the connection property.

Comment: +1 for the using block. As a side note: you can remove the curly-braces for the outer using block in this case (when there is no code that resides only in the outer block).

Answer (score 9):

You should at least put single quotes around the email adress:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  sumant SET email='" + email + "' WHERE code ='" + textBox2.Text + "' ", con);
```

However, this is not a good way of passing in params, as you are leaving this wide open for SQL injection attacks...

A better way would be to use a parameterized query, like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  sumant SET email=@email WHERE code=@code", con);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", textBox2.Text);
```

Then you don't need to supply the single quotes, and you're at the same time safeguarding against SQL injection attacks...